# How to make an axios post request that is structured like a form post request?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, axios, next.js

I am having some problems with trying to customize some code for Next-Auth, an authentication library for.Next.Js.

I want to be able to use Axios to manually make the post request rather than using a `<form>` element.

When I do the following, I have success.

```
<form method='POST' action='/api/auth/signout'>
   <input name='csrfToken' value={csrfToken}/>
   <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

But, when I try to do the same thing with axios, it doesn't work. I am attempting to call Next-auth's Signout endpoint, which I can do just fine using this html form element. I am expecting that the application with log the user out when calling this endpoint. When I do so with the form input, then it logs the user out. When calling the same endpoint with axios, it does not log the user out and instead nothing is happening

My axios request is

```
  const submitForm = async () => {
    if (csrfToken) {
      const params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.append("csrfToken", csrfToken);
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          method: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signout",
          data: params,
          headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
        }).then((res) => console.log(res));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

I have tried adding additional headers that I saw on the request that works properly, like:

```
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
  "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1"
```

I have tried making it multipart form data, passing it simply a body of {csrfToken}, and anything else I could think of.

Any tips or things that I might be overlooking?

I can't figure out why I am unable to make this work. I am using ANTD, rather than using regular html `<form>` elements throughout the application and would love to be able to use that additional functionality.

Edited:

I found the solution after a lot of headache. It turns out that everything was functioning as it should have previously, but Next-Auth has an issue with updating the client-side 'session' object when you make a manual change on the server side.

I fixed this by doing  the following:

```
        const res = await axios.post("/api/auth/signout", { csrfToken }).then(
          async ({ request: { responseURL } }) =>
            await router
              .push(responseURL)
              //this is from https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/596#issuecomment-943453568
              //force the client side to refresh and revalidate since it doesn't want to do so on its own.
              .then(() => document.dispatchEvent(new Event("visibilitychange")))
              .catch((err) =>
                console.log("err refreshing client side session ", err)
              )
        );
```

The trick that i was missing was the `document.dispatchEvent(new Event('visibilitychange')`. This is the magical piece that allows you to force the client side next-auth session to sync with cookies/db.
see here for more info https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/596#issuecomment-943453568

Comment: when you say success what do you mean ?

Comment: in your form the csrf’s input have no name…, have you tries the devtools (network tab) to see the request parameters and body structure?

Comment: oops thank you @adirabargil - I updated my question. I do have a name on the input field in the form, apologies for leaving it off.

From dev tools, I can see that my post request receives a 302 status code and has a request of `csrfToken: xxxxxxtoken}`